# My DropDownListFor presents error only post back

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

My dropDownListFor display data correctly but when I go to the HttpPost displays the error System.NullReferenceException.

My viewModel:

```
public class contaModel
    {
        public SelectList responsaveis { get; set; }
        public List<int> idResponsaveis { get; set; }

        public SelectList responsaveisCartao { get; set; }
        public List<int> idResponsaveisCartao { get; set; }
    }
```

The moment I enter date in select List:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            contaModel model = new contaModel();

            model.responsaveis = new SelectList(db.responsavelporconta, "IdResponsavelPorConta", "Nome");
            model.responsaveisCartao = new SelectList(db.responsavelporconta, "IdResponsavelPorConta", "Nome");


            return View(model);
        }
```

The line that generates the error:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.idResponsaveis, Model.responsaveis)
```

I using List because i work with multiples dropdowns in my page.

Comment: what exactly are you doing with that postback?

Comment: I have a button that copies the node of dropdowns as needed by the user, my return is to be a list of selected ids, so use List <int>. With these ids, I associate the elements of the bank as much responsible for the card.